# Trying to purge MySQL fails

Tags: apt, 15.04, mysql, error-handling, purge

I'm running in circles currently, trying to fix some mysql problem.

I couldn't use apt-get for a while now, because it always stuck at the line `Setting up mysql-server-5.6 (5.6.27-0ubuntu0.15.04.1) ...` and didn't let me do anything. So I tried to reinstall mysql, purging it. While I was able to remove `mysql-server` and `mysql-client` eventually, I'm still unable to purge `mysql-common`. Obviously, I managed to corrupt something, but how can I get my system back and running at this point?

```
...:~# apt-get purge mysql-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mysql-common*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 423600 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mysql-common (5.6.27-0ubuntu0.15.04.1) ...
Purging configuration files for mysql-common (5.6.27-0ubuntu0.15.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/my.cnf corrupt: invalid status
dpkg: error processing package mysql-common (--purge):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

-

```
...# sudo dpkg -P --force-all mysql-common
(Reading database ... 424733 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mysql-common (5.6.27-0ubuntu0.15.04.1) ...
Purging configuration files for mysql-common (5.6.27-0ubuntu0.15.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for my.cnf
dpkg: error processing package mysql-common (--purge):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-common
```

-

```
...:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

My goal is to just get it back and running again (mysql).

Comment: I don't think you ought to have a file `my.cnf` in `/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives`. To be sure, do `update-alternatives --query mysql-common`. That will probably fail as well, but if the output looks relevant, please add it to your question. If it simply fails with a similar message, remove `/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives` and try the purge operation again.

Comment: As you expected, `update-alternatives` only gave out `no alternatives for mysql-common` again. I noticed that `/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/my.cfg` seemed to exist. As you suggested, I moved the whole folder before trying to redo the purge operation, but the result stays the same as above. No change / effect.

Comment: `sudo dpkg -P --force-all mysql-common`

Comment: @A.B. I tried that and added the output to my question - sadly, same effect: `no alternatives for my.cfg`

Comment: What's the output of `cat /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/my.cnf`

Comment: And try a `awk '/etc/ {system("sudo touch "$1)}' /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/my.cnf; sudo apt-get purge mysql-common`

Comment: If that not work: `sudo sed -i 's/update-alternatives/# update-alternatives/' /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-common.postrm`

Comment: @A.B. The result is: `cat: /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/my.cnf: No such file or directory` - Tryingto create a new `my.cnf` doesn't change any output. The awk script returns basically the same as before (file not found) but I'll add the output to my question for you in a minute

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33689/discussion-between-a-b-and-katai).

Comment: @A.B. That last command had no output - but it worked! I could purge without error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some words in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33689/discussion-between-a-b-and-katai), here is the solution:

```
sudo rm /etc/alternatives/my.cnf
sudo ln -s /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf /etc/alternatives/my.cnf
```

---

Why? The file `/etc/alternatives/my.cnf` **has to be** a link and nothing else.

That was the error message:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config my.cnf 
update-alternatives: warning: alternative /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf (part of link group my.cnf) doesn't exist; removing from list of alternatives
update-alternatives: error: unable to read link `/etc/alternatives/my.cnf': Invalid argument
```