# Unable to uninstall MySQL 5.7 from Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, mysql

I have the following results

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mysql-server-5.7
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 48.3 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 230940 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/my.cnf corrupt: invalid status
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

$ sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'mysql-server' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mysql-server-5.7
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 48.3 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 230940 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/my.cnf corrupt: invalid status
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

$ sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql-server-5.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mysql-server-5.7
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 48.3 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 230940 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/my.cnf corrupt: invalid status
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: did you try **apt-get autoremove mysql-server**

Comment: Try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/715320/trying-to-purge-mysql-fails

Comment: Hey there, just saw your comment. Here is what I get:
'
isaac@isaac-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx:~$  apt-get autoremove mysql-server
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
'

Comment: Here is an error I get:

Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Follow the answer from @A.B. in my link.

Comment: isaac@isaac-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx:~$ sudo rm /etc/alternatives/my.cnf
isaac@isaac-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx:~$ sudo ln -s /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf /etc/alternatives/my.cnf
isaac@isaac-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config my.cnf
update-alternatives: error: /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/my.cnf corrupt: invalid status

Comment: So, yeah, I keep getting errors.

Comment: Provide the content of the file `/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/my.cnf `

Comment: `
port          = 3306

socket        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

auto
/etc/mysql/my.cnf

/etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback
100

skip-networking

# bind-address = 127.0.0.1
`

Comment: Additionally, there was another my.cnf file, but it seems to be broken/corrected/no connection, and thus was moved to the trash bin.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.